# Android Tabs with Maps

Tags: android, tabs, maps

I am trying to create an application for android with three tabs (which i already did with this tutorial: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/ because it should work on a big number of devices) and two of them should show maps.

I looked up for tutorials for this case but i did not find something fitting. So how do i do that?
Can someone please help me or give a link which explains something like that?
I hope the question is easy to answer for you and i am grateful for every answer.

**Update:
i tried something out now but the way i try does not work:
Full code:**

xml:

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.navigationtabdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    TabHost tHost;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tHost.setup();

    /** Defining Tab Change Listener event. This is invoked when tab is changed */
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            AndroidFragment androidFragment = (AndroidFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("android");
            AppleFragment appleFragment = (AppleFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("apple");
            MapsFragment mapsFragment = (MapsFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("maps");
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            /** Detaches the androidfragment if exists */
            if(androidFragment!=null)
                ft.detach(androidFragment);

            /** Detaches the applefragment if exists */
            if(appleFragment!=null)
                ft.detach(appleFragment);

            /** Detaches the mapsfragment if exists */
            if(mapsFragment!=null)
                ft.detach(mapsFragment);

            /** If current tab is android */
            if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("android")){

                if(androidFragment==null){
                    /** Create AndroidFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AndroidFragment(), "android");
                }else{
                    /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                    ft.attach(androidFragment);
                }

            }else{    /** If current tab is apple */
                if(appleFragment==null){
                    /** Create AppleFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AppleFragment(), "apple");
                 }else{
                    /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                    ft.attach(appleFragment);
                }

          /**  }else{ */        /** If current tab is maps */
                if(mapsFragment==null){
                    /** Create MapsFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new MapsFragment(), "maps");
                 }else{
                    /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                    ft.attach(mapsFragment);
                }
            }
            ft.commit();
        }
    };

    /** Setting tabchangelistener for the tab */
    tHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);

    /** Defining tab builder for Android tab */
    TabHost.TabSpec tSpecAndroid = tHost.newTabSpec("android");
    tSpecAndroid.setIndicator("Android");
    tSpecAndroid.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
    tHost.addTab(tSpecAndroid);

    /** Defining tab builder for Apple tab */
    TabHost.TabSpec tSpecApple = tHost.newTabSpec("apple");
    tSpecApple.setIndicator("Apple");
    tSpecApple.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
    tHost.addTab(tSpecApple);

    /** Defining tab builder for Maps tab */
    TabHost.TabSpec tSpecMaps = tHost.newTabSpec("maps");
    tSpecMaps.setIndicator("Maps");
    tSpecMaps.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
    tHost.addTab(tSpecMaps);

}
}
```

DummyTabContent:

```
package com.example.navigationtabdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

public class DummyTabContent implements TabContentFactory{
    private Context mContext;

    public DummyTabContent(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        return v;
    }
}
```

AndroidFragment:

```
package com.example.navigationtabdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AndroidFragment extends ListFragment{

    /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
    String android_versions[] = new String[]{
        "Jelly Bean",
        "IceCream Sandwich",
        "HoneyComb",
        "Ginger Bread",
        "Froyo"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
}
```

AppleFragment:

```
package com.example.navigationtabdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AppleFragment extends ListFragment{

    /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
    String apple_versions[] = new String[]{
        "Mountain Lion",
        "Lion",
        "Snow Leopard",
        "Leopard",
        "Tiger",
        "Panther",
        "Jaguar",
        "Puma"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, apple_versions);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
}
```

MapsFragment.java:

```
package com.example.navigationtabdemo;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMyLocationChangeListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else {    // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting event handler for location change
        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

}
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.navigationtabdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.navigationtabdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.navigationtabdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>       

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>    

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.navigationtabdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAw4me2T-HBcFiTocAucxdbhVxLD1u3n6g"/>        

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to be a bit tricky to do until the [MapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) came out. You will need to replace your generic fragment with a MapFragment. You will also need a API key etc. as you would if you created a map with an MapActivity. For more information check the Android Google Maps developer guide.

From the point of UX, maps in tabs might not be the best idea. If you create swipe views with tabs, you are going to have two views that are scrollable. If you don't, you'll only be able to switch tabs with buttons at the top of the screen.

Comment: I would use the buttons you have click on anyway and i already figured out how to use maps with its API key etc...
but how exactly do i  make use of the mapfragment in the tabs now?

Comment: Why does MapsFragment.java have a MapsActivity in it? Your fragment that host maps should extend a MapFragment and not an FragmentActivity. MapFragment is a subclass of Fragment and FragmentActivity is is subclass of Activity.

Comment: i changed MapsActivity to MapsFragment but still some mistakes which are probably easyly fixed:

XML: Fragment: android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"

MapsFragment.java:  public void:TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);


MainActivity: public void: MapsFragment mapsFragment = (MapsFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("maps");

/** Detaches the mapsfragment if exists */
                if(mapsFragment!=null)
                    ft.detach(mapsFragment);

ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new MapsFragment(), "maps");

 ft.attach(mapsFragment);